# Android media player in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-mediaplayer

I'm new to android and building a chatroom app with voice messages similar to WhatApp or Messenger. So far I am able to create and upload the voice note to my server as well as play it back on the device. However, I am having an issue wrapping my head around how I should be handling the playback so that only one voice note is being played at a time. I was able to get only one message to playback at a time by initializing the media player in the ListAdapter then calling mp.stop() if the mediaplayer is playing. However, each time I chose to play another voice note my timer and seekbar for the last two voice notes activated are being updated.

I'm thinking that maybe I'm approaching this issue incorrectly. The below code resides in my view class.

```
// Runnable
private Runnable onEverySecond = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!isPaused){
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                // Update seekbar position
                position = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                // Displaying time completed playing
                playTime.setText(AppUtils.milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
                seekBar.setProgress(position);
                // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
                seekBar.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 100);
            }else{
                if(listener != null) listener.onAudioStoppedListener(true);
            }
        }
    }
};

// Play button
actionButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Play button clicked!");
            if (isPaused) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                }
                setMediaPlayer();
                setIsPlaying();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(position);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                updateProgressBar();
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                setPaused();
            }
        }
    });


private void setMediaPlayer() {
    try {
        String fileName = getFileName();
        File filePath = new File(MyApp.getVoiceNoteDir() + fileName);
        if (filePath.exists()){
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filePath.getPath());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();

            seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
            seekBar.setProgress(0);
            playTime.setText(AppUtils.milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));
            actionButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_pause_light));
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.stop();
                    seekBar.setProgress(0);
                    actionButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_play_light));
                    setPaused();
                }
            });
        }else{
            checkFile();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


void setPaused(){
    isPaused = true;
    actionButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_play_light));
}

void setIsPlaying(){
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.stop();
    isPaused = false;
    actionButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_pause_light));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a service to handle MediaPlayer actions. Do not do media stuff in the adapter or in list.

By creating a separate service for Media actions, you will have single MediaPlayer instance. Where if you ask it to play particular file, you can also handle to stop/reset previous playing file.

I could find a [tutorial link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-song-playback--mobile-22778) for you to do this via service.